# Create role providers programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

Is there a way to create several role providers programmatically (without a mention in Web.config) with different properties and choose which to use in `Roles` class each time?

(This may look a crazy hack, but I consider other alternatives as well.)

Comment: Why do you want it to be dynamic? If you need grater flexibility and granular control, you can look at [ASP Security Kit](http://ASPSecurityKit.net)

Comment: @Varun, thanks, but I have other ideas of how to solve the problem, other than paying you $500 for your kit. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. The role provider is set upon application initialization, and is not meant to change. 
But maybe you could create your own interactive role provider and set it only once as required.. This role provider can act as an adapter to the other available implementations..